# How should \n be dealt in text while training for NER ? Should they be removed or replaced by space?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, conv-neural-network, spacy

I have documents where often the ORG name will come as follows(separated by newline):

```
Name_Part1 Name_Part2
Name_Part3
```

Here, I would like to training a NER model using spacy CNN. Should I be replacing `'\n'` by `' '` (space) or leaving as it is. Will there be issues in sentence boundary detection?

Is there any industry standard method or protocol for this process?

Comment: what are you trying  to create custom Entity  model or using built-in model like en_core_web _sm?

Comment: I am using built-in en_core_web_sm and have trained this model with my data. I am currently replacing the '\n' with  ' '.    
                                                            
I combine 3 sentences(as determined by spacy) together at once and use it as  my text to determine the entity. So, sen1, sen2, sen3 and sen4 will be comb_sent1 (sen1 + sen2 + sen3) , comb_sent2(sen2 + sen3 + sen4) and so on.

Comment: You don't have to train data it is already prepared model only you need to tokenize sentence and apply the model. or give me normal paragraph and expected result. I will let you know how to do it.

Comment: Buddy you can retrain the base spacy model using transfer learing or even create a model from scratch.

Comment: Please give me raw text and expected results.